# how to change DNN 7 Mega2DNN to Standard DNN menu

Tags: dotnetnuke

I has some problem, can anyone help?
how to change DNN 7 **Mega2DNN** to Standard DNN menu.
so it is one column going down

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The DDR Menu uses templates to conteol its behavior.  Mega2DNN is one such template?

Assuming that the template is specified in your skin file, that's where you replace Mega2DNN with another template.  Look at a skin file from the Gravity skin as an exmaple.

You will find a small collection of templates at http://dnnddrmenutemplates.codeplex.com/

The DNN Wike has a section on the DDR Menu, including a discussion of creating and configuring templates.

You may find it easy to modify an existing template, or you can create one from scratch.  As for getting started, the ULTokens template creates a simple unordered list of links that you can style.  The Superfish template creates a horizontal menu with dropdowns.

DNNCreative.com, a subscription site, has a nice tutorial